# Placing a line inside the iTextFile PDF generated file

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-4.0, itext

I'm trying to place a line separator in the footer of the generated PDF document using iTextSharp like following:

```
   public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
        int pageN = writer.PageNumber;
        String text = "Page " + pageN + " / ";
        float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 8);
        Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;
        cb.SetRGBColorFill(0, 0, 0);
        cb.BeginText();

        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
        cb.SetTextMatrix(pageSize.GetRight(90), pageSize.GetBottom(90));
        cb.ShowText(text);
        cb.EndText();
        cb.AddTemplate(template, pageSize.GetRight(90) + len, pageSize.GetBottom(90));

        // line separator is here
        cb.SetLineWidth(2.0f);   // Make a bit thicker than 1.0 default
        cb.MoveTo(20, document.Top - 40f);
        cb.LineTo(400, document.Top - 40f);
        cb.Stroke();

    }
```

I'm trying to place the line exactly below the page number like following:
[image]

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4,50,50,120,40);
```

Where values are:

```
50 - margin left
50 - margin right
120 - margin top
40 - margin bottom
```

The MoveTo and LineTo method accept parameters as following:

```
MoveTo(x axis, y axis);
LineTo(x axis, y axis);
```

Can someone help me out to calculate this? :)

Edit:  Just did it

```
   cb.MoveTo(50f, 80f);
   cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width-document.RightMargin, 80f);
```

Just in  case someone else in the future needs it;

Comment: If you answer your own question, then please write an answer.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse done :)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse You guys built hell of library for C#ers all around the world. It'd be amazing if iText had designer support so that we can simply drag & drop the items onto the designer and design the whole thing (it'd ease the work completely) :)

P.S. I love the library even like this, and I prefer using it over the built in MS reports or Crystal reports ! :)

Comment: We're not preventing anyone else to create such a designer on top of iText, but at this moment it's not our core business. You'd be amazed how many other things one can still do with pdf! If you should ever create designer software on top of iText, be sure to drop us a line, we're always interested in what others are doing with our software. :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this trick did it (for those who might need it in future):

```
   cb.MoveTo(50f, 80f);
   cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width-document.RightMargin, 80f);
```

These are the values that I've calculated based on my PDF document's margin that I've shown in my question and they are:

```
50
50
120
40
```

You can tell how it's done just by looking at the numbers passed into the LineTo and MoveTo methods;

Cheers